# How to programmatically select RadioButton in an activity

Tags: android, radio-button, selected

In my project, I get the value of the gender from the database as 0 and 1.
0 for male and 1 for female.
Based on this values, I need to check the corresponding RadioButton in a RadioGroup.
If 0 is pressed, radio0 will be checked or radio1 will be checked.
I don't know how to check the radio button based on this string values...
This is the code I tried:

```
      String gendd=ViewProfileActivity.participantview.get(4);
      System.out.println("Gender:::::"+gendd);

      male=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
       female=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
       if(gendd.equals("0")){

           male.setSelected(true);
           female.setSelected(false);
       }
       else
           {
           male.setSelected(false);

           female.setSelected(true);

           }
```

But it fails. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Code look oke, have you debugged your code? What was the value of gendd? Did it enter the if or else block?

Comment: it got values like 0 or 1

Comment: Top tip: use `"0".equals(gendd)` in string comparison better, this way the first string will never be null and you might avoid unpleasant NullPointers in the future

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this.

```
   if(gendd.contains("0"))
    {
       male.setChecked(true);
       female.setChecked(false);
   }
   else
   {
       male.setChecked(false);
       female.setChecked(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

You shoud use `check(radioButtonId)` method on parent RadioGroup.

E.g.

```
radioGroup.check(gendd.equals("0") ? R.id.radio0 : R.id.radio1);
```

(assuming the comparison holds as the types haven't been mentioned)